# Kill a PM2 Cron Job automatically after 72 hours?

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2, cron-task

I have a PM2 with a Cron Job that run every 5 minutes

```
pm2 start shoot-msg.sh --name shoot-messages -i 4 --cron "*/5 * * * *"
```

How can I program the PM2 to quit after 72 hours and kill the cron job ?

Meaning I don't want to do `pm2 delete all` by myself...

Comment: where is this PM2 used? windows/linux?

Comment: @deechris27: Linux , Ubuntu

Comment: did it help with your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Your need is a task scheduler in Ubuntu. Use Crontab to kill the process after 72 hours.

1. Install crontab

   `sudo apt install cron`
2. Set it to run in the background

   `sudo systemctl enable cron`
3. Edit the crontab

   `crontab -e`
4. Select the editor

   1. /bin/nano        <--- default
   2. /usr/bin/vim.basic
   3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
   4. /bin/ed

press `ENTER` to select the default nano.

The editor would show the below,

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

5. Scroll to the bottom of the editor and add the kill command with cron

   `0 */72 * * * /bin/node /bin/pm2 delete all`

Just replace these values (/bin/node, /bin/pm2) by what is on the /etc/init.d/pm2-init.sh file.

6. Save `CTRL+O` and exit `CTRL+X`